# HowTo access digital and analog IO ports using Win 10 IoT

Tags: windows, arduino, raspberry-pi, iot

Where can I find "how to" articles and samples about accessing IO ports using Win 10 IoT on Raspberry 3?
Furthermore: What is Win 10 "Arduino Virtual Shield" and "Arduino Remote Experience"?
Any recommendations for IO libs?
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Find documentation and samples on [Windows 10 IoT Core Samples](https://github.com/ms-iot) 
 and a getting started on [The Internet of your things](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot)